# How to disable caching on get call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to disable cache on getting a request in vue environment. I already tried this but it does not work.

```
api.js (file)

getCall: () => {
        return performAsyncGet(apiConfig.getCall.url, 
requestConfigJSON, _REQUEST_TOKENS.getCall, apiConfig.getCall.cache)
            .then(
                    response => response.data
        );
    },
```

```
(apiConfig.js) (file)



    getCall: {
        url: `${servicePathPrefixOrDomain}/api/getCall`
         cache: false
    }
```

Does anybody know how to disable the cache, when making a get request in vue.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your problem in brief

Comment: when making a get request, its get data from caching. I would like to make this get request caching: false

Comment: It seems you are want to change the value of `caching` variable from the `getCall`, If I'm right then tell me when you want to make `true` and when `false`

Comment: I will like to have always cache: false. When making (get call)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid caching you can make your url unique by appending timestamp as a querystring parameter like this:

```
getCall: {
        url: `${servicePathPrefixOrDomain}/api/getCall?_t={new Date().getTime()}`
         cache: false
    }
```

In this way for every ajax call the url will be unique due to different timestamp and browser will not cache the response.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I already solved in the headers. Adding const requestConfigJSON = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

Is solved adding the next code in the header:

```
const requestConfigJSON = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
};
```